# Uploaded video and streamio-ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert an uploaded video file directly to a gif using streamio-ffmpeg in my Rails application.

How can I directly read the uploaded video (an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object)by streamio-ffmpeg?

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(params[:video])
TypeError: can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to IO (ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile#to_io gives Tempfile)


movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(params[:video].open)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of File into String

movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(params[:video].read)
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8


File.open(params[:video].path) do |file|
  movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(file)
  options = {frame_rate: '10', duration: '00:00:6.000'}
  movie.transcode("test.gif", options)
end
TypeError: no implicit conversion of File into String
```

Answer (score 1):

`movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(params[:video].tempfile.path)`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add more description on your answer.